# Network Security Services for Java (Mozilla JSS) for Mac UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, security, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have recently compiled Mozilla JSS (Network Security Services for Java) for my 64bit Mac (OS X 10.6.8) for use in a Java project.  The project is being created using Eclipse.

I have added the path for the compiled JSS libraries to the Eclipse project by defining the Native Library Path on the Java Build Path.

However, I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError on libsmime3.dylib even though it is on the same Native Library Path as defined for libjss4.jnilib.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users//nss-jss/mozilla/dist/Darwin10.8.0_64_OPT.OBJ/lib/libjss4.jnilib:
>   Library not loaded: @executable_path/libsmime3.dylib   Referenced
>   from: /Users//nss-jss/mozilla/dist/Darwin10.8.0_64_OPT.OBJ/lib/libjss4.jnilib
>   Reason: image not found

After Googling around a bit (and trying several different things), I thought that maybe the dylib extension needed to be jnilib for reasons I don't quite understand for the Mac.  I didn't change the makefiles to create a jnilib file instead of a dylib file, but just changed the extension.  That didn't work.

Since there are many, many dylib files for JSS, I expect that changing the makefiles will take some effort.

Before I spent a lot of time attempting the modifications, I thought I would check out SO to see if there was something to help me out.  I didn't find anything that solved my issue, hence this post.

I would greatly appreciate any advice with JSS in mind as the solutions that I have found for UnsatisfiedLinkError all are for the project in question.

Regards,
Todd

Comment: Do you have the file `libsmime3.dylib` somewhere on a path which is a part of the `system.library.path` ?

Comment: I have checked what the system declares java.library.path and placed with all the other JSS libs on that path as well as setting the Native Library path (equivalent of -DlibaryPath) via Eclipse, but still have the same error.

Comment: Take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41742307/1218618), your problem with NSS is the same which is explained on my answer with `@executable_path`.