# Where does @executable_path point to in a Java program

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface, dylib

I'm trying to load a native library in Java on Mac OS X 10.10.5 like this:

```
System.loadLibrary("SgCore_wrap");
```

and it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/nyholku/sgCoreTest/libSgCore_wrap.dylib: dlopen(/Users/nyholku/sgCoreTest/libSgCore_wrap.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libsgCore64.dylib
```

So my question is where does `@executable_path` points to in case of a Java program and does this depend on weather I run from command line or within Eclipse?

And further, supposing the correct location is 'somewhere in the system' like say '/Library', what is the best strategy handle this in a distributable Mac OS bundle (.app) with embedded JVM?

This what my otool shows for the two libraries involved (functions in libSgCore_wrap.dylib call functions in libsgCore64.dylib)  in question:

```
otool -L /Users/nyholku/sgCoreTest/libSgCore_wrap.dylib 
   /Users/nyholku/sgCoreTest/libSgCore_wrap.dylib:
      libSgCore_wrap.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
      /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 104.1.0)
      @executable_path/../Frameworks/libsgCore64.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
      /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

and here otool output for the

```
 tool -L /Users/nyholku/sgCoreTest/libsgCore64.dylib 
    /Users/nyholku/sgCoreTest/libsgCore64.dylib:
       @executable_path/../Frameworks/libsgCore64.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
       /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 157.0.0)
       /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
       /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
       /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.14.0)
```

As a bonus question, why does libSgCore_wrap.dylib reference itself and what does it mean/effect as far where the library should be?

Comment: AFAIK @executable_path is the actual executable, i.e. `java` in a Java program without a wrapper binary. Pretty useless. Had to use DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH the last time I came across such a library.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too and also thought about DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH, but now read somewhere that all DYLD_ are ignored in the interest of security...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you copy directly the `.dylib`s from some other application to your user folder and then you're trying to load it with Java.

The problem is that the references on these libraries are using `@executable_path` which is relative to the main executable (the other application) and when Java try to load these libraries the reference using `@executable_path` are not correct, so `dlopen` can not find the required dependencies.

A possible solution for your specific case is to use `@loader_path` instead since this variable is relative to the referring binary.

So if you only need this two libraries, and you can work with a copy of them without worrying about update on theirs etc, and both are on the same directory, then you can try to copy the libraries and change their references from `@executable_path` to `@loader_path` using `install_name_tool`.

As you show in your code I suppose that both libraries are in the same path `/Users/nyholku/sgCoreTest/` and since you're using `System.loadLibrary` method you're setting correctly `-Djava.library.path=/Users/nyholku/sgCoreTest/`.

First, change the reference to `libsgCore64.dylib` inside `libSgCore_wrap.dylib` file using the follow command `install_name_tool -change oldReference newReference dylibToChange`, in your case:

`install_name_tool -change @executable_path/../Frameworks/libsgCore64.dylib @loader_path/libsgCore64.dylib libSgCore_wrap.dylib`

Then you must change the identifier of the `libsgCore64.dylib` itself, using `install_name_tool -id newReference dylibToChange`, in your case:

`install_name_tool -id @loader_path/libsgCore64.dylib libsgCore64.dylib`

Now you can use these modified libraries and they will load correctly in Java.